# How to disable select dropddown using ng-disabled

Tags: angularjs

I have a div for ul li and i want to disable select dropdown when li items are zero.so iwant to know how to write ng-disabled on select button when li items in ul is 0.
I hav tried on select element

```
<select id="currency" ng-disabled="( $('#ulYAxis li div label').length==0)" 
        ng-model="unit" ng-change="CurrencySymbolClick()"> .
```

---

```
<select id="currency" ng-disabled="( $('#ulYAxis li div label').length==0)" 
         ng-model="unit" ng-change="CurrencySymbolClick()">
    <option value="">Select Currency</option>
    <option value="$">$(Dollar)</option>
    <option value="€">€(Euro)</option>
    <option value="£">£(Pound)</option>
    <option value="¥">¥(Yen)</option>
 </select>
```

This is my select dropdown

---

This is my select dropdown and i have

```
<ul class="newwidgetsevendiv_bubble_uldiv" id="ulYAxisSize" 
    ondrop="dropYaxis(event)" ondragover="allowDropYaxis(event)">
</ul> 
<label id="yAxisSize" class="seriesyaxis" 
       style="display: none; clear:both; ">
</label>
```

this is my ul

Comment: Could you show us your code?

Comment: <select id="currency" ng-disabled="( $('#ulYAxis li div label').length==0)" ng-model="unit" ng-change="CurrencySymbolClick()">
                                       <option value="">Select Currency</option>
                                        <option value="$">$(Dollar)</option>
                                        <option value="€">€(Euro)</option>
                                        <option value="£">£(Pound)</option>
                                        <option value="¥">¥(Yen)</option>
                                    </select> This is my select dropdown

Comment: can you tell me now how to disable select dropdown now.Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In AngularJS, expressions are evaluated against a scope object. If you want to run more complex JavaScript code, you should make it a controller method and call the method from your view.

```
̶<̶s̶e̶l̶e̶c̶t̶ ̶i̶d̶=̶"̶c̶u̶r̶r̶e̶n̶c̶y̶"̶ ̶n̶g̶-̶d̶i̶s̶a̶b̶l̶e̶d̶=̶"̶(̶ ̶$̶(̶'̶#̶u̶l̶Y̶A̶x̶i̶s̶ ̶l̶i̶ ̶d̶i̶v̶ ̶l̶a̶b̶e̶l̶'̶)̶.̶l̶e̶n̶g̶t̶h̶=̶=̶0̶)̶"̶ ̶
<select id="currency" ng-disabled="noLabel()" 
         ng-model="unit" ng-change="CurrencySymbolClick()">
    <option value="">Select Currency</option>
    <option value="$">$(Dollar)</option>
    <option value="€">€(Euro)</option>
    <option value="£">£(Pound)</option>
    <option value="¥">¥(Yen)</option>
</select>
```

```
$scope.noLabel = function {
    return $('#ulYAxis li div label').length==0
};
```

Comment: Thanks it is working $scope.noLabel = function() {
    return $('#ulYAxis li div label').length==0
    };

Comment: but we have to have include $scope.noLabel = function() {
    return $('#ulYAxis li div label').length==0
    };

Comment: Read [AngularJS Developer Guide - JavaScript expressions vs AngularJS expressions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#angularjs-expressions-vs-javascript-expressions).

Answer (score -1):

I do not know if I understood your question well. You want to show select button only when there are items? If so, you can use `ng-if` statement, here is an example:

```
<div>
    <button ng-if="items.length > 0">Select</button>
    <button ng-if="items.length <= 0" disabled>Select</button>
    <ul ng-repeat="i in items">
      <li>{{i.name}}</li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

JS:

```
$scope.items = [{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "item1"
},
{
  "id": 2,
  "name": "item2"
}]
```

Comment: I want to enable select dropdown when ul li length is more than zero and by default i has to disable it

Comment: <select id="currency" ng-disabled="( $('#ulYAxis li div label').length==0)" ng-model="unit" ng-change="CurrencySymbolClick()">
                                       <option value="">Select Currency</option>
                                        <option value="$">$(Dollar)</option>
                                        <option value="€">€(Euro)</option>
                                        <option value="£">£(Pound)</option>
                                        <option value="¥">¥(Yen)</option>
                                    </select>

Comment: This is my select dropdown and i have       <ul class="newwidgetsevendiv_bubble_uldiv" id="ulYAxisSize" ondrop="dropYaxis(event)" ondragover="allowDropYaxis(event)"></ul>
                                    <label id="yAxisSize" class="seriesyaxis" style="display: none; clear:both; "></label>this is my ul